# Accessing jupyter notebook running on GCP VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, cloud, virtual-machine

How can I access Jupyter notebook running on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine (VM instance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way! I need to connect to VM via terminal like this:

```
gcloud beta compute --project "MY_PROJECT_NAME" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b" "MY_VM_NAME" -- -L 8005:127.0.0.1:8888
```

And then I can access jupyter notebook via browser on address `http://127.0.0.1:8005/`